# Как анимировать градиент?

Tags: css, css-animation

У меня есть css код:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(20deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(40deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(60deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(80deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(100deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(120deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(140deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(160deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(180deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(200deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(220deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(240deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(260deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(280deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(300deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(320deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(340deg, 100%, 50%), hsl(360deg, 100%, 50%));
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #373737;
}
```

это код который делает thumb радужным как в палитре цветов.

И мне нужно как-то анимировать чтобы градиент двигался с верху вниз.

Простите если я невнятно объяснил...

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
 
@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

---

- [Сборник анимированных градиентов](https://snipp.ru/html-css/animated-gradient)
- [Ещё анимированные градиенты](http://css.yoksel.ru/animation-for-gradients/)
- [Using CSS animations (developer mozilla docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)
- [CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)
- [О Использовании градиентов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients)
- [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

---

```css
.css-selector {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00ffbd, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400% 400%;

    -webkit-animation: AnnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: AnnimationName 30s ease infinite;
    animation: AnnimationName 30s ease infinite;
}
@-o-keyframes AnnimationName {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnnimationName {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnnimationName {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
@keyframes AnnimationName {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%}
}
```

```html
<div class='css-selector'>

</div>
```

[Css Gradient Animator](https://www.gradient-animator.com/)

Comment: Не работает. Я могу отправить полный код HTML и CSS

Comment: @Yar1k, Смотрите внимательно. В первом примере достаточно просто исправить направление градиента(градус - 180). Где-то ошиблись. У меня все работает. Добавил второй вариант(вертикальный градиент). Он так же учитывает разные браузеры. Скорость переливания самого градиента думаю вы в силах установить самостоятельно

Comment: @Yar1k, полный код не требуется, лишь та часть куда вы хотите пихнуть этот градиент. Я думаю вы немного запутались в своих же стилях. Но это не точно